# AttributeError from gensim running LDA model

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I'm trying to run a simple LDA model on Gensim:

```
from gensim import corpora
#text_data here is a list of tokens
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(text_data)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in text_data]

lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, num_topics=5, id2word=dictionary, passes=15)
```

and getting the following error:

```
File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.random_state = utils.get_random_state(random_state)

  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 84, in get_random_state
    return np.random.mtrand._rand

AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'mtrand'
```

I have tried `from numpy import random` but doesn't seem to work, and not really sure why this error is thrown.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Restarting Anaconda and Spyder fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you try `from numpy import *` and re-run it.

Comment: It's weird. Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: @Chirag, nope that doesn't work either.